# Ensuring balanced canvas save/restore in case of error

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

When doing graphics in HTML5/ECMAScript/JavaScript, a very common pattern is to perform a context.save(), apply a coordinate transform, and then do a context.restore().  Unfortunately, the design of HTML5 seems to persist things like transforms as part of the canvas even if a drawing context is discarded and recreated; if an error occurs while the coordinates are transformed the drawing context will be left in a messed-up state "forever".

If every piece of code which use save/restore is guarded by a `try` block, it can ensure that the context gets restored when it exits.  If any piece of code which uses a `save` throws an exception without restoring context, however, that will cause any restore operation by a calling context to restore the incorrect state.

Is there any clean way of doing something like:

```
var savedContext = contextCapturer.capture(context);
try
{
   ... code that might call a save without restore
}
finally
{      
  savedContext.restore();
}
```

I think it might be possible to have a context-saver object modify the save/restore methods of context so that they would keep a count that it could then use to ensure things are balanced, but I'm not sure how such code could be written so as to work correctly even if it calls, or is called by, other code that does likewise.  It's not necessary that the saved context remain usable once the `restore` executes; what's necessary is that if code in the "try" block performs e.g. five saves and three restores, the `savedContext.restore()` operation must perform two extra restores on the context to make up for the imbalance.

To clarify, I'm thinking about things like the showFramed method here; given a procedure which expects to draw in the range defined by `inRect` it transforms the coordinates and clips so that it will appear in the range defined by `outRect` (and also in this case draws a yellow border).

```js
function showFramed(ctx, inRect, outRect, bColor, bWidth, proc)
{
  ctx.save();
  ctx.strokeStyle=bColor;
  ctx.lineWidth=bWidth;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(outRect[0],outRect[1],outRect[2],outRect[3]);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();
  
  ctx.save();
  ctx.clip();
  ctx.translate(outRect[0],outRect[1]);
  ctx.scale(outRect[2]/inRect[2], outRect[3]/inRect[3]);
  ctx.translate(-inRect[0],-inRect[1]);
  proc();
  ctx.restore();
}

function showScreen(ctx)
{
  var i;
  ctx.beginPath();
  for (i=0; i<=160; i+=10)
    {
      ctx.moveTo(i,0);
      ctx.lineTo(0,160-i);
      ctx.lineTo(i/2+80,i/2+80);
      ctx.lineTo(160-i,160);
    }
  ctx.stroke();
}

function showScreen2(ctx)
{
  showScreen(ctx);
  ctx.save();
  ctx.strokeStyle="#007F00";
  showFramed(ctx, [0,0,160,160], [20,90,60,60], "#FFFF00", 3,
            function() {showScreen(ctx); });
  ctx.strokeStyle="#7F0000";
  showFramed(ctx, [0,40,80,80], [90,90,60,60], "#FFFF00", 3,
            function() {showScreen(ctx); });
  ctx.restore();  
}


function demo1()
{
  var c=document.getElementById("canv");
  var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.strokeStyle="#0000FF";
  showScreen2(ctx);
}

function demo2()
{
  var c=document.getElementById("canv");
  var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

  ctx.strokeStyle="#00FF00";
  showFramed(ctx, [0,0,160,160], [80,10,60,60], "#FFFF00", 3,
            function() {showScreen2(ctx); });
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canv" Width=160 height=160></canvas>
<button onClick="demo1()">Demo1</button>
<button onClick="demo2()">Demo2</button>
```

The `drawFramed` method has no idea what transform will be applicable when it's entered.  If an exception gets thrown from within the passed-in procedure, it shouldn't be swallowed, but I would suggest that `showFramed` should nonetheless restore the context to what it was before it was entered; should it not?